# Python List Duplication Removal but saving duplicates

Tags: python

I have a nested list of lists. I need to compare a top level list to the sub lists and save the duplicates of each list into a new list. I've tried set and list comprehensions but once I try to turn those into a loop to iterate through the lists I run into issues example data below with expected returns:

```
topList = [list1[1,2,3], list2[3,4,5], list3[5,6,7]]
listofVals = [1,4,7]
```

I would expect a return of a new list of lists containing `resList[[1],[4],[7]]`, the intent is to replicate this with more data so the sample data here is simple to provide proof of concept. I normally work in C so pointer math and just deref'ing values to do a direct compare isn't viable for my application or if it is my python fu is not the best.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but I think this works? `[[num] for each_list in topList for num in each_list if num in listofVals]` can you clarify what `list1` and `list2` and `list3`are and remove it from your code as it's not a proper [mcve]

Comment: its a list of  ints and i just want to compare a list to that list of lists but create a new list of lists with the duplicated values, basically a big spread sheet can go down and show duplicates row by row

Comment: I'm not sure that means _duplicated_ necessarily

Comment: your solution works! thank you! my list comprehension skills are not good haha

Answer (score 2):

@ Umar.H provided the solution thank you!

```
[[num] for each_list in topList for num in each_list if num in listofVals]
```